# Bash script & scope - contents of my script doesn't seem to affect my file system?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting

Just got a new job and want to be able to switch between my work/personal github accounts easily. I know there are many solutions to this but this is not my question (though any simple and easy solutions are welcome).

If I write the following into my terminal, it will remove all my current SSH keys from the agent and avoids any conflict:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s` 
ssh-add -D
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

I can then run ssh-add -l and it will list just the one RSA key (my work key). Normally I have 4 in the agent which causes conflicts. But with this it is great, I can easily use my work github with no problems.

To avoid having to cut and paste, or type it out every day, I tried putting it into a bash script. The script seems to work and it displays the same messages as if I typed it straight into terminal, (agent PID, and lists only one key etc), but if I run ssh-add -l after, it displays all 4 ssh keys and causes me the same conflict.

So why is that? Does the bash script not affect files outside of it or something? Is there some kind of scope issue or permissions I'm not aware of? Here's my script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 eval `ssh-agent -s` 
 ssh-add -D
 ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is called in a subshell which does not affect the current shell. Call the script so that it runs in your current shell:

```
. my_ssh_script.sh
```

Comment: I had to use "source" in place of the shorthand "." on my ubuntu system for some reason, but it works now - thanks for your quick explanation